# Why didn't Wanda keep a small Hex in the end?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

At the end of the show, Wanda

> completely undid the Hex. The Vision and children disappeared.

I mean, why didn't Wanda keep a small Hex with only her husband and children living inside? They can interact with the outside through S.W.O.R.D drones, radio, and Monica.

Comment: So keep them in a prison that they can never leave or they'll die?

Comment: Ummm..for example, suppose there is an incurable disease patient who can't move, should we kill him/her?

Comment: @Harry: Ummm, did we create this patient ourselves three weeks ago using magic, as a coping mechanism for our own grief?

Comment: Are they really even different people? I thought they were simply an aspect of Wanda herself -- her idea of The Vision. It's like waking up from a dream -- the people in that dream don't die, they were part of you the whole time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*WandaVision* down to its bare roots is a show about Wanda overcoming the grief, loss and trauma she has suffered her whole life. She lost her parents at a very young age, then lost her twin brother, her only other family in the world. Not long after that she gets a new family but that is ripped apart with them at each others throats. She then loses Vision, her new anchor in the world and is essentially alone again. *"You took everything from me."*

> Matt Shakman: Probably, for sure. In the end, there's so many great ideas that you have as you make something, and you come up with a million things that you don't end up using. **Because ultimately, the story that we're telling is a story about grief and how you overcome loss, and how you move on after you've suffered so much trauma.**
>
> <sub>[Screen Rant, Matt Shakman Interview: WandaVision](https://screenrant.com/wandavision-show-director-matt-shakman-interview/)</sub>

For the story arc and character development to complete and for Wanda to move on it doesn't make any sense for her to create a mini Hex for the boys. She's finally decided to spend some time on her own and learn more about her powers as well as cope with her grief. However, that's not to say she's never going to try and bring them back, remember the post-credits scene for the final episode shows her reading the Darkhold and then hearing both Tommy and Billy's voices.

I think you've also got to consider the ethical and moral concerns over a mini Hex for the boys. The Hex, as created, was a static boundary, which rejected others coming into it. That means that unless Wanda is always around to let people in and out then those inside are completely isolated. They can't ever leave and they can't ever see anyone else. That means they also can't ever leave that small area you have them trapped in. Is that something you'd want for your loved ones? This is just the reasons related to those inside as well, you've got other concerns for those existing outside but nearby too.

We're also at a point in the story for Wanda where she's only just discovering who she is. She doesn't know the extent of her power or how to control it. She leaves to be on her own to learn more. It might be that she wants to bring them back but doesn't want them in a Hex because of the above. So she's gone away to learn deeper and more powerful magic so she can bring them back to live a normal life.

You're also forgetting about White Vision. White Vision is the Vision created from original Vision's body. He's still out and about somewhere, we don't see him again after he leaves Memory Vision. Presumably Wanda wouldn't want to create a whole new Vision again if she can find White Vision and be happy with him.

Comment: Let's just hope a sequel doesn't undo this conclusion.

Answer (score 17):

It would defeat the point of the show.

The show is essentially about Wanda going through the five stages of grief.

**Stage 1: Denial...**

In the first episodes you can see how Wanda acts like it is all normal, she pretends that everything is fine... that Vision is alive and that she has a happy life... while we all (including her) know that it's a lie.

**Stage 2: Anger...**

We can see this whenever her Hex is threatened (first by Monica, later by S.W.O.R.D ) she lashes out with her power to protect the little world she has created. (Sure she doesn't kill anyone but that's mainly because she is a "hero" and a show where the hero kills innocent people won't sit well with many fans).

**Stage 3: Bargaining...**

Bargaining is pretty much a "what if" situations, when you are no longer able to deny that there is a problem you start to think...but what if I can fix it with this? Or this? That's why she was so easy to accept the new Pietro even though he looked nothing like her real brother... she wanted it to be real because if that was real then why could the rest not be real?

**Stage 4: Depression...**

This is later seen in the more modern setting in the show, where she has trouble getting out of bed and starts to slack off more and more towards her family. At this point she is forced to face her true feelings.

**Stage 5: Acceptance...**

At this point she has accepted that Vision is dead and her children aren't real and that she is alone... she needs to to be able to continue with her life because without acceptance she would live a lie and would never be able to be truly happy.

So the reason why the Hex got completely stopped is because it is the natural conclusion of her journey to be able to move on with her life and accept what has happened.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible she did ...

> In a [post-credits scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmqPMWlNzKM), we see Wanda at a remote cabin, sipping coffee. When the camera moves inside, we see an Astral Wanda poring over the book she acquired from Agatha (in much the same way we saw Doctor Strange do so in *Infinity War*). There's a strange voice-over that happens, where we hear the boys yelling for her to "Help us! Please!". After a brief moment, she waves her hand across the screen, cutting off their voices and ending the scene.

Comment: FWIW I'd be surprised if this is meant to indicate her having kept them alive in some sort of Hex somewhere. More likely she's learning more powers and can now either communicate with them somehow or is getting the power to bring them to life properly. I imagine it'll be explained in DS2 though so looking forward to that!

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to nail down what this actually means, but it does heavily imply the boys simply did not vanish with the hex (I think it's likely "Red" Vision is gone). It also doesn't rule out she made some sort of mini-hex somewhere out there so they wouldn't vanish. It's also possible she did this without realizing she did it.

Comment: re: *"Red" Vision is gone* - except that he passed his memories into White Vision, and of course Vision being Vision, he can alter his appearance in any way he chooses (including looking just like a normal human), so for all practical purposes, he may not be gone at all.  His original memories (as well as the new ones since his "death") are now in his original body, so he's more "back" than he was at the start of the show.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I thought he just unlocked the memories being hidden from White Vision not passed memories over?

Comment: Yeah, that was my understanding too. He basically showed him all the previous MCU stuff that SWORD had hidden from him. If Red really had implanted himself into White, I doubt White would have left Wanda to grieve Red alone.

Comment: Potato, potahto, I guess.  White may or may not be missing his memories from Red's time in the Hex, that part doesn't really matter, but he's at least still got all his pre-death memories, so his feelings for Wanda are probably still there in some form.  My impression is that he left her because he has mixed feelings about a version of him having been created, manipulated and trapped in the Hex by her, and needs some alone-time to come to terms with it, but will ultimately forgive her and come back, but we'll obviously have to wait and see.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Potato Potahto... I thought the entire point of his monologue/dialogue during combat was to point out that philosophers can quibble over such trivial things until the end of time ;-)