# When did Wanda turn evil again?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness, scarlet-witch

Is there any material covering Wanda's actions during the period between the end of *WandaVision* and the start of *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*?

At the end of *WandaVision*, Wanda walks away from her dreamworld fantasy life, making tough choices and earning respect from Monica Rambeau and Sword.

At the start of *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, she's living inside a new hex, has picked up some evil magic book, and is generally wallowing in her heartbreak.

Is there a bridge between these two points in print or film? Or are we supposed to just accept that the tough act didn't last and this is what happens with buyer's remorse? And where did the book come from?

Comment: The book was in WandaVision

Comment: FWIW, I thought it was a bit of an abrupt swivel too.

Comment: I'd say she never stopped, she merely took a break and regrouped.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Agatha Harkness brought the Darkhold with her to Westview.

After defeating her, Wanda took the book and went to her remote cabin. As seen in the post-credit scene of the final episode of WandaVision, she was studying the book in her astral form and looking for her children.
It is during this time she gets corrupted by the Darkhold, until Doctor Strange comes to visit her.

Comment: Another post-credit scene I managed to miss. Thank you.

Comment: Tagging in the related post credit questions on the site;[Small Hex](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250221/why-didnt-wanda-keep-a-small-hex-in-the-end?rq=1), [Projecting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250269/is-wanda-astral-projecting?rq=1),[The Book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244226/origins-of-the-book-used-by-wanda-in-the-post-credit-scene?rq=1)